# Why isn't this roblox dialog script working

Tags: lua, roblox

so I want the game to take a specific action when a dialog option is selected.

```lua
script.Parent.DialogChoiceSelected:connect(function(player,choice)
    if choice.Name == "No" then
        player.Character.Humanoid.Health = 0
    elseif choice.Name == "Yes" then
        player.Character.Humanoid.Health = 1000
    end
end)
```

The script is enabled, it's placed in the same dialog event as the choices, and I know the dialog names are correct, but when the dialog choice is selected absolutely nothing happens. So someone please explain to me how the ****

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the docs for [Dialog.DialogChoiceSelected](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/Dialog/DialogChoiceSelected) there's this line :

> This event is client-side only and will not fire on the server. It should be connected to in either a LocalScript or a ModuleScript required by a LocalScript.

So you'll need a [LocalScript](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/LocalScript) in one of the appropriate locations to connect to this Dialog object and then your code should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a script in your dialog, it wouldn't work because it is client-side so it has to be a LocalScript and it has to be a descendant of either:

A Player's Backpack, such as a child of a Tool
A Player's character model
A Player's PlayerGui
A Player's PlayerScripts
The ReplicatedFirst service.

And then change the local script's code to be workspace:WaitForChild("TheDialogName").

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/LocalScript

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Dialog